# Simple Html5 Canvas operation slows down browser

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I've been playind with canvas lately and started today to work on using setInterval to refresh / animate it regularly.
I was surprised to see how this is heavy for the cpu and slows down eveyrthing. Looking at example online I m sure there is something wrong with my way of doing. I then simplified what I wanted to do at the maximum (not playing with image but rectangles, not using too many objects, etc) but still got the same problem.

I was trying to get a white flash (at 12fps) on top of two rectangles...So nothing complicate at all...

Here is my code.

```
function Canvas(name){
this.ctx=document.getElementById(name).getContext('2d');
this.canvas=this.ctx.canvas;
this.width=this.canvas.width;
this.height=this.canvas.height;
this.layers=new Array();

this.draw = function() {
this.canvas.width = this.canvas.width;
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.rect(0,0,this.width,this.height);
    this.ctx.closePath();
    this.ctx.fillStyle="#eaeaea";
    this.ctx.fill();
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.rect(250,50,300,250);
    this.ctx.closePath();
    this.ctx.fillStyle="#ff0000";
    this.ctx.fill();

    intensity=Math.random();
    this.flash(intensity);
 };

this.flash = function(intensity) {
    this.ctx.globalAlpha = intensity;
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.rect(0,0,this.width,this.height);
    this.ctx.closePath();
    this.ctx.fillStyle="#fff";
    this.ctx.fill();
    this.ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    setInterval(this.draw.bind(this),1000);
};

function initCanvas(){
mycanvas=new Canvas('myCanvas');
mycanvas.draw();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    initCanvas();
});
```

---

Solution found:

Use [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) instead of [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp).

Comment: To mark an answer as a solution, click the tick mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Close all the paths, which you open:

```
this.draw = function() {
    this.canvas.width = this.canvas.width;
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.rect(0,0,this.width,this.height);
    this.ctx.closePath();    //Closing
    this.ctx.fillStyle="#eaeaea";
    this.ctx.fill();
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.rect(250,50,300,250);
    this.ctx.closePath();    //Closing
    this.ctx.fillStyle="#ff0000";
    this.ctx.fill();

    this.flash(40);
};

this.flash = function(intensity) {
    this.ctx.globalAlpha = intensity;
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.rect(0,0,this.width,this.height);
    this.ctx.closePath();    //Closing
    this.ctx.fillStyle="#fff";
    this.ctx.fill();
    this.ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    setInterval(this.draw.bind(this),1000);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got a massive memory leak because you keep using `setInterval` in the `flash` function. Let's look at the sequence of events

- mycanvas object created
- draw()
- draw calls flash
- flash sets an interval to call `draw` every second
- draw calls flash and sets another interval
- Process repeats till you've got a lot of intervals calling `draw`

To solve it, use `setTimeout` in `flash`. So it calls `draw` after a second, which calls `flash` and then calls `draw` again in a second. Also, 1000ms won't give you 12fps. 1000/12 will.

Also, use `ctx.closePath();` to close the paths you opened with `beginPath()`

You also never closed the `Canvas` function with a `}`.

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AKSmS/)

Comment: Of course ! Thanks!
I didn't read properly on setInterval...
The 1000 was only for test It put 40 now for 25fps. And it works fine.

Comment: @user1531617 If that solves your problem, mark the answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is relevant anymore, but I found myself in a similar situation and wanted to give an even better answer.
Use `requestAnimationFrame(yourLoop)`, especially for games since it is faster and has better performance.
http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/